# use local JSON file with react and electron

Tags: json, reactjs, electron

so I have created an electron App with the help of react.js.
The app should mainly display charts, for which I use chart.js. The data of the chart files need to be updated monthly, since I get new data every month from another department per Excel, which I quickly export to a JSON. Obviously I don't want to create a new production electron app every month. So is it possible to retrieve data from json files after production? I can't find anything on the web unfortunately.

How do I go about that, since I can't access JSON files outside of my src folder with react or can I?

thanks in advance!!

Comment: Never worked with Electron, so can't properly answer, but I think you need this API to open files from FS: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/dialog

Answer (score 0):

Electron is for creating desktop apps so you have full access to the file system.

To read a local file you can install and use Node [fs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html). `fs` supports Promises, callbacks and synchronous methods.

Rather than hardcode the filepath, you probably want to do some friendly UI stuff like on first launch, ask the user to select the file they want to load and then store that path as a preference. Then on subsequent launches, test if the file exists and load it, otherwise alert the user to pick another file, etc.

```
let thePath = "/Users/Spring/Desktop/ticket.txt" 

var fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile(thePath, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
  if (err) return console.log(err);
  // data is the contents of the text file we just read
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion! From what I have understand fs is, just like you said, a node module, therefore server side. Obviously I can use node modules within my electron app, but I want to make the UI for my electron App with React and here I can't use server side modules, like fs, unfortunately. That's basically the issue I am having, since I at first need to create my React app, compile it and from that compiled vanilla JS version of my React app I need to compile the electron App. So I am not sure whether/how I can use fs already in my React app. :/

Comment: @Thomas - I don't know React so I can't suggest anything but it seems weird that you shouldn't be able to use `Node.js` modules with React. Also, you can do all your file reading in your `main` process – no React there since there is no UI – and then send the data to your `renderer` for display. Good luck!